# loadmore function working on grid view but not with list view on the same page

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

In my view page there is two types of views grid view and list view.in grid view load more function is working properly but when i choose list view load more function is not working there..
this is my view page..

```
  <div class="tab-pane fade  in active" id="shop-grid-tab">
    <div class="row ">

        <div class="shop-product-tab first-sale container2"> 

        <!-- product start -->

        <?php foreach($mengalery as $row){?>
        <?php $images=json_decode($row->image);{?>
        <div class="item">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="product_list">
            <div class="single_product"> 
            <a href="#"  target=""><img class="slb" src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $images[0];?>" alt="" /></a>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php }}?>
        <!-- col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 end --> 




      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- list view product-->
   <div class="tab-pane fade " id="shop-list-tab">
    <div class="list-view container2"> 

      <!-- single-product start -->
     <?php foreach($mengalery as $row){?>
      <?php $images=json_decode($row->image);{?>

      <div class="row list ">
      <div class="item">
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="product_blog_image">
            <div class="product_blog_image"> <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>hardpolo_control/details"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $images[0];?>" alt="" /></a> </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

     </div>

      <?php }}?>

    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- single-product end -->
```

this is my controler...

```
public function men()
{  
    $data['active_mn']='men';

    $data['mendropdown']=$this->Hardpolo_model->get_category_by_parent($p_id=8);
    $data['kidsdropdown']=$this->Hardpolo_model->get_category_by_parent($p_id=9);
    $data['accessoriesdropdown']=$this->Hardpolo_model->get_category_by_parent($p_id=21);
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'Hardpolo_control/men';
    $config['per_page'] = 6;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Hardpolo_model->count_images($p_id=8);
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<span class="next a">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</span>';
    $data['mengalery']=$this->Hardpolo_model->get_all_images($p_id=8,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->load->library('pagination',$config);
    $data['page_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('men',$data);
}
```

this is my script..

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>


 <script>
 var ias = $.ias({
 container: ".container2",
 item: ".item",
 pagination: "#pagination",
 next: ".next a"
 });

  ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());            
  ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({offset: 2}));
  ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({
  text: 'There are no more pages left to load.'      
 }));
 $(function () {
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
 })
 </script>
```

i had given classname as container2 for both view and i had given different classname values and all but its not working

Comment: Please do not expect anyone to read this much code. Reduce your problem to a [mcve].

Comment: yaa..sorry i will try to reduce it